# Laravel + CKEditor + CKFinder

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

Has anyone encountered the setting up of CKFinder in Laravel? The CKEditor works fine, and when I integrate the CKFinder into it, I get this error: [screenshot](https://bit.ws/share/CKFinder_3_-_File_Browser_2017-11-29_09-41-43.png)

Comment: Well, your ckfinder.js trying to access connector.php using absolute path to connector, but this url probably doesn't say anything to laravel, i think, you should either make view for ckfinder in laravel or make alias in your webserver point to ckfinder connector.php

Comment: Check the official [CKFinder package for Laravel 5.5+](https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package) - hopefully this will make the integration easier.

Answer (score 1):

use this :
https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package#configuring-authentication
in samples 
you will see ckeditor and ckfinder

in git bash or cmd or terminal

```
   composer require ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package
   php artisan ckfinder:download
   php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckfinder
```

create directory on public folder. the name should be userfiles
for middleware use

```
   php artisan make:middleware CustomCKFinderAuth
```

on config/ckfinder.php
change this code:

```
   $config['authentication'] = '\App\Http\Middleware\CustomCKFinderAuth';
```

on middleware class use

```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
    config(['ckfinder.authentication' => function() {
        return true;
    }]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: It's better to post some code with explanation here than just copying the link.